# Error "Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to perform a `SELECT` from my database, but I'm getting an error and I don't understand why. All I can tell is that it seems to be failing at the `prepare()` statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$sQuery =  "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE `email` = ? AND `password` = ?";
$sTypes = "sss";
$aParams = array("user", "john.doe@missing.com", "password");
```

Above is the query and bind_param values.

```
function conn($sQuery, $sTypes=null, $aParams=null){
    $sMessage = '';
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','myvyn') or die('unable to connect!');
    if($db->connect_errno){
        $message = $db->connect_error;
    } else{
        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        if (!($stmt->prepare($sQuery))) {
             var_dump("Prepare failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
        }   
        if($sTypes&&$aParams){
            $bindParams[] = $sTypes;
            foreach($aParams as $param){
                $bindParams[] = $param;
            }
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bindParams);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $oResult = $stmt->get_result();
        while($rows = $oResult->fetch_assoc()){
            $aRows[] = $rows;
        }
        $oResult->free();
        $db->close();
        return $aRows;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use parameters for a table name, as per [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) (my bold):

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value.
>
> However, **they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column names),** in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a SELECT statement, or to specify both operands of a binary operator such as the = equal sign. The latter restriction is necessary because it would be impossible to determine the parameter type. It's not allowed to compare marker with NULL by ? IS NULL too. In general, parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements, and not in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

Assuming you *control* the table name (so SQL injection is impossible), you could use something like:

```
$sQuery =  "SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE `email` = ? AND `password` = ?";
```

and then only bind the email address and password.

Comment: If it comes from user input, `$tblName` should be checked against a whitelist before being injected into the query.